# 3gpp and mp4 on android

Tags: android, video, mp4, codec

I uploaded some video file from Android phone which was shoot by the built in video recorder app. The video file format is shown as mp4 when it is played.

When I uploaded to amazon s3, the result is a file of extention 3gpp.

Why is that? What should I do to convert the file in s3 from 3gpp to mp4 format?

Comment: why don't you do the video conversion in App?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the actual video file itself should not have changed unless you have used some conversion services also, or converted as part of your upload procedure - to test this you can take one of your video files from S3 and change the extension from .3gpp to .mp4 and check it plays properly.

You don't include your upload code, but to make sure that S3 knows the correct file type make sure you set the 'content-type' field in the HTTP multipart MIME post you send to S3.
For mp4 files this should be:

- content_type=video/mp4